# Issue in AddColumn dropdown options

Tags: magento-1.9, adminhtml, custom-options, renderer

I want to add some column as a drop drown with some values (not in grid)but I can't get Them , I don't know why !

[image]

**Test 1:**

```
$this->addColumn('somme', array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('Somme'),
            'style'   => 'width:100px',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'options'   => array(0 => $this->__('Value1'), 1 => $this->__('Value2')),
            'sortable'  => false,
        ));
```

**Test 2:**

```
$this->addColumn('somme', array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('Somme'),
            'style'   => 'width:100px',
            'type'    => 'options',
            'renderer' => 'Module_ModuleName_Block_Config_Adminhtml_Renderer_Dropdown',
        ));
```

**Module_ModuleName_Block_Adminhtml_Renderer_Dropdown**

```
class Module_ModuleName_Block_Config_Adminhtml_Renderer_Dropdown extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_Widget_Grid_Column_Renderer_Abstract{
    public function render(Varien_Object $row) {
        $html = '<select>';
        $html .= '<option value="0">Value1</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="1">Value2</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        return $html;
    }
}
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

### **I found the solution :**

**Module/ModuleName/Block/Config/Somename.php**

```
<?php
class Module_ModuleName_Config_Somename extends Mage_Adminhtml_Block_System_Config_Form_Field_Array_Abstract
{
    protected $_itemRenderer;

    public function _prepareToRender()
    {
        $this->addColumn('somme', array(
            'label'   => Mage::helper('module')->__('Somme'),
            'style'   => 'width:100px',
            'renderer' => $this->_getRenderer(),
        ));
    }
    protected function _getRenderer()
    {
        $this->_itemRenderer = $this->getLayout()->createBlock(
            'module_moduleName/config_adminhtml_form_field_conditions', '',
                array('is_render_to_js_template' => true)
        );
        return $this->_itemRenderer;
    }
}
```

**Module/ModuleName/Block/Config/Adminhtml/Form/Field/Conditions.php**

```
<?php

class Module_ModuleName_Block_Config_Adminhtml_Form_Field_Conditions extends Mage_Core_Block_Html_Select {

    public function _toHtml()
    {
        $html = '<select>';
        $html .= '<option value="First">First value</option>';
        $html .= '<option value="Second">Second value</option>';
        $html .= '</select>';
        return $html;
    }

    public function setInputName($value)
    {
        return $this->setName($value);
    }
}
```